# Lipschitz function with $0$ derivative a.e. is constant on connected components

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

I have to find a reference on a book of the following fact:

> a Lipschitz continuous function whose derivative is $0$ wherever it exists is constant on connected components of its domain

Does someone know some book where this statement is proved?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lipschitz functions are absolutely continuous, and many books prove the fundamental theorem of calculus for absolutely continuous functions, from which the result follows. A particular reference for this could be Chapter 7 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Answer (score 0):

The *definition* of "absolutely continuous" makes it clear that a Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous. Now the big theorem about absolutely continuous functions says qed.